# What is BIND_NOW on Linux ELF?

Tags: linux

When resolving the functions derived from Shared Libraries I had a problem and realized that the problem is related to `BIND_NOW` which is one of security features for ELF.

Since there was not enough information online, I couldn't go further at the moment. what is `BIND_NOW`?

Answer (score 3):

It means to resolve the symbols right while loading the object (instead of when being used, which is called lazy binding)

Quoted from `man 3 dlopen`:

```
One of the following two values must be included in flag:

   RTLD_LAZY
          Perform lazy binding.  Only resolve symbols as the code that
          references them is executed.  If the symbol is never
          referenced, then it is never resolved.  (Lazy binding is
          performed only for function references; references to
          variables are always immediately bound when the library is
          loaded.)

   RTLD_NOW
          If this value is specified, or the environment variable
          LD_BIND_NOW is set to a nonempty string, all undefined symbols
          in the library are resolved before dlopen() returns.  If this
          cannot be done, an error is returned.
```

**EDITED:** Also see [this link](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/qnxcar2/index.jsp?topic=/com.qnx.doc.neutrino.prog/topic/devel_Lazy_binding.html), which I've found while Googling.